# Что лучше sudoedit или nano?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Здравсвуйте всем! Решил я тут упростить себе немного жизнь в терминале и сделать парочку алиасов для команд для этого отредачил файлик ~/.bashrc в nano перезапустил всё работает, но вот вопросик один назрел: в чём лучше было бы его редачить (nano или sudoedit)?

Просто как бы есть темы о том, что файлы защищённые можно редачить только через sudoedit, а если выдавать права то будет крах системы)) это я знаю

Так в чём же лучше?

Comment: mcedit лучше чем это

Comment: @ArchDemon, Сарказм оценил.

Comment: Если у вас прав на модификацию файла хватило и так, то зачем вам sudo ? sudoedit используется для модификации файлов, которые с вашими правами не доступны.

Comment: Океюшки, спасибо! Значит с nano можно смело добавлять алиасы, а то просто в гайдах всё через VIM делают. Мне аж страшно стало, вдруг что-то сломал))

Comment: Всё что лежит в `~` принадлежит пользователю, т.е. вам. Если для доступа к вашим файлам от вас требуют права рута, то это какое-то недоразумение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`visudo` по умолчанию выбирает тот редактор который обозначен в системной переменной `$EDITOR`  для терменальной ссессии или `$VISUAL` для гуя.

```
~$ echo $EDITOR
/usr/bin/emacsclient -cn
```

Это например относится к командам  `vsudo`  и `git -c -a -m "анотация"`

В вашем случаце командочку можно подкоречить типо такого оборотика:

```
export VISUAL=/usr/bin/fancy-mancy-edetrancy
export EDITOR=$VISUAL
# запускаем все это дело через
eval $EDITOR file
```